# Other than heap size what would limit the number of elements a HashMap can hold

Tags: java, hashmap

As per the title - what constrains the number of elements a HashMap can hold and what data structure could be used instead.

Comment: there are no other constraints regarding the item count if linked lists are used to resolve conflicts. of course performance will suffer if the items per slot ratio is bad

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `hashCode` returns an `int` instead of a `long` also prevents `HashMap` from being efficient much beyond 2^32 entries.

Comment: @JohanSjöberg: I see no reason why you couldn't have more than 2^31 *entries*.  You can't have more then 2^31 *buckets*.  I was just pointing out that if you fix the bucket problem (with a two-level array, say) you still have to fix the `hashCode` problem.

Answer (score 1):

One thing is the maximum array size, which in Java is [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).

If that's a limit to you, then you could create your own class which wraps a list of `HashMap` objects or use a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

The only constraint would be array size (2^31-1) and the number of unique values possible for your key type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think there are limitations.

Firstly, an object's hashCode will fit always in the maximum array size as the largest int value gives the maximum array size.

Secondly, afaik a HashMap uses lists for their keys. Therefore, if two keys have the same hashCode (which may happen even if you insert only some values) they will be inserted anyway. Since a list can get as long as you want there are no real limitations besides the efficiency of it.

Answer (score 0):

The `HashMap` data structure is backed by an array for the hashtable under the hood.  Because Java array sizes must be specified using integers, they are limited in size to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (about 2 billion elements).

If constant-time lookups of more elements are necessary, I suppose you could wrap nested `HashMap`s in your own class definition, but you're also going to have to get around the fact that Java's `Collection` interface specifies an `int` size value - in a nutshell, it's possible to have a data structure that stores more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements, but this is not truly supported by anything in the `Collection` interface.

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of the heap size that you've already mentioned I do not believe there are any hard limits on the number of items you can place into a HashMap.

Internally HashMaps have an array of 'buckets', with each bucket being a linked list. When you add an item it is hashed to find the correct bucket, and is then added to the front of that linked list. As such, even if every bucket has one item in it, adding one more item will simply add the item to the linked list in the bucket.

The behaviour I've described above is the implementation of the HashMap class that comes with the Oracle JRE and may differ on other platforms, and so other platforms may have limitations on the number of items that can be placed into them.

It is also worth pointing out that if you are putting more than Integer.MAX_VALUE items into a HashMap, the lookup performance will degrade considerably because the HashMap will have to iterate over the list when trying to find the item.